# cannot use instance member within property initializer DropDown library

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

i have implemented [assistolab](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) dropdown in my project.but in some viewcontroller it could not work properly.it shows,

> cannot use instance member within property initializer
>   my code snippet is given below

```
class MobileTopUpVC: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    let dropDown = DropDown() //error is here

    @IBOutlet weak var mobileTopUpImag: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNumberTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var operatorTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var DropDown: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var backGroundView: UIView!
    var textArray = [UITextField]()
    var countryArray:[String] = colors.countryArray
    var operatorArray:[String] = colors.opArray





    @IBOutlet weak var proceedButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        backGroundView.layer.cornerRadius = backGroundView.frame.width/2
        backGroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        //countryArray = colors.countryArray
          backGroundView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        backGroundView.layer.borderColor = colors.second.cgColor
        textArray = [countryTxt,operatorTxt,amountTxt,mobileNumberTxt]
        let view1:UIView! = UIView()

        view1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        countryTxt.inputView  = view1
        operatorTxt.inputView  = view1
//        countryTxt.layer.borderWidth = 1
//        countryTxt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
//        countryTxt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.bezel
        borderStyle()
        proceedButton.Cradius(size: 15.0)
        mobileTopUpImag.image = mobileTopUpImag.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        mobileTopUpImag.tintColor = colors.second
        countryDropDown()
    }
```

the error is troubling me in this line

```
let dropDown = DropDown()
```

please help me to resolve this

Comment: have you imported import DropDown?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following so your DropDown is initialised in the viewDidLoad

and also change your View name From "DropDown" to something else :D

```
class MobileTopUpVC: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    let dropDown: DropDown? //Changed**

    @IBOutlet weak var mobileTopUpImag: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNumberTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var operatorTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDownView: UIView! // Change your VIEW NAME!!!

    @IBOutlet weak var backGroundView: UIView!
    var textArray = [UITextField]()
    var countryArray:[String] = colors.countryArray
    var operatorArray:[String] = colors.opArray





    @IBOutlet weak var proceedButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dropDown = DropDown()




        backGroundView.layer.cornerRadius = backGroundView.frame.width/2
        backGroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        //countryArray = colors.countryArray
          backGroundView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        backGroundView.layer.borderColor = colors.second.cgColor
        textArray = [countryTxt,operatorTxt,amountTxt,mobileNumberTxt]
        let view1:UIView! = UIView()

        view1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        countryTxt.inputView  = view1
        operatorTxt.inputView  = view1
//        countryTxt.layer.borderWidth = 1
//        countryTxt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
//        countryTxt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.bezel
        borderStyle()
        proceedButton.Cradius(size: 15.0)
        mobileTopUpImag.image = mobileTopUpImag.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        mobileTopUpImag.tintColor = colors.second
        countryDropDown()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using DropDown class as property name. Check below line in your code-

@IBOutlet weak var DropDown: UIView!

It should be something like this-

@IBOutlet weak var dropDownView: UIView!